# Access S3 using boto3 (python) without credentials?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-vpc

I have a client application that has implicit access to an S3 bucket. This access is granted by the client application residing in a VPC, and routing S3 traffic to a VPCE endpoint, and then configuring a S3 bucket policy that allows S3 operations from that VPCE.

The client application has the expected access to S3 for the various application functions that need to access S3. However, I am unable to use boto3 from this client application to access S3, because it is throwing a `NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials`.

It seems that credentials are required in boto3, regardless of if the S3 bucket requires it or not. Is there any option to tell boto3 to remove this requirement for credentials? Or create dummy credentials?